# How to add paragraph written file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
file_object = open("file.txt","w")
username = input("Enter your username here: ")
password = input("Enter your password here: ")
file_object.write(username)
file_object.write(password)
file_object.close()
```

How can I separate username and password with a paragraph on output file (`file.txt`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `file_object.write("\n")` should create a line break.
`\n` is the newline escape sequence

Comment: Thanks, that's want I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a newline if you want each username and password on different lines, you also need to open with the [mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) set to `a` to append new data each time and not overwrite every time you reopen the file:

```
with open("file.txt","a") as file_object:
    username = input("Enter your username here: ")
    password = input("Enter your password here: ")
    file_object.write("{},{}\n".format(username, password))
```

So for  `username = "foo` and `password = 1234` will write foo,1234 to your file, then on the next input  `username = "bar` and `password = 5678` your output file will look like:

```
foo,1234
bar,5678
```

using `with` means your file
 will be closed automatically so there is no need to explicitly call close

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to have only one file_object.write on my code.

Comment: No worries, you can format the data however you want, if you want space delimited data use  `file_object.write("{} {}\n".format(username, password))`, when reading you might find the csv lib useful, it will split the data for you, each row will have `["username","password"]`

Comment: Thanks again! It opened my mind for another options thath I have not heard about

Answer (score 0):

Added better password handling:

```
from getpass import getpass

separator = ";"

with open("file.txt","w") as file_object:
    username = input("Enter your username here: ")
    password = getpass("Enter your password here: ")
    file_object.write(separator.join([username, password]) + "\n")
```